# How to make two different GitHub pages as example.github.io and example.github.io/notifications?

Tags: github, git-branch, github-pages

My GitHub username is S1Live. I have a repository called notifications. So, a GitHub page has been made as example.github.io/notifications. I want to make another page as example.github.io or example.github.io/index.html.

Is it possible? If yes, then how to do it?

Comment: I want to make two repositories. 1 will host something like example.github.io and the other one will host something like example.github.io/notifications

Comment: You have to make one repo for the base site and one for each `/repo` page: https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a repo named `username.github.io` to host something on a subdomain.
And by creating a repo as `notifications` under `example` user, you could make a website as example.github.io/notifications. [Reference](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)

Comment: By the word, if my username is example, and if I make a repository by the name(example.github.io), then I could get the exact Website. But how to make the other website (example.github.io/notifications)?

Comment: Can I do it,by making a repo as "notifications" ?

Comment: Will it become "example.github.io/notifications" ?

Comment: Yes, by creating a repo as `notifications` under `example` user.

Comment: Complete the question and I'll choose it as right answer.

Comment: Good. You did it!

Answer (score 0):

**example.github.io** is the main *index.html* file in the root folder. 
**example.github.io/notifications.html** is the *notifications.html* file in the root folder.

to get **example.github.io/notifications** without ".html" in the end you could try make a folder named notifications and put another index.html file there.